# from a single column of cities what sql query would you run to make a column of city permutations

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anyone please help me to build this query:

from a single column of cities what sql query would you run to make a column of city permutations.
E.g: if city column has a b c d then I should build new colUmns such as a,b; a,c; a,d; b,c and so on..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join` with an inequality:

```
select c1.city, c2.city
from cities c1 join
     cities c2
     on c1.city < c2.city;
```